# I have a class object in one view model. I would like to pass this object state to another View Model in MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

In AttachmentViewModel I have the following code

```
public ICommand EditAttachmentCommand { get; private set; }

public AttachmentsViewModel()
{
    EditAttachmentCommand = new ActionCommand<AvailAttachment>(EditAttachment);
}
private void EditAttachment(AvailAttachment attachment)
{
    var attachmentDetailsViewModel = Router.ResolveViewModel<AttachmentDetailsViewModel>(true,            ViewModelTags.ATTACHMENT_DETAILS_VIEWMODEL);
    attachmentDetailsViewModel.NavigateToAttachment(attachment.ArticleId);
    EventAggregator.Publish(ViewTags.ATTACHMENT_DETAILS_VIEW.AsViewNavigationArgs());
    EventAggregator.Publish(new CurrentViewMessage(ContentView.Attachment));
}
```

In my MainViewModel I have the following code:

```
public ICommand SessionAttachmentCommand { get; private set; }
public MainMenuViewModel()
{
    SessionAttachmentCommand = new ActionCommand<AvailAttachment>(EditAttachment);
}

private void EditAttachment(AvailAttachment attachment)
{
    var attachmentDetailsViewModel = Router.ResolveViewModel<AttachmentDetailsViewModel>(true, ViewModelTags.ATTACHMENT_DETAILS_VIEWMODEL);
    attachmentDetailsViewModel.NavigateToAttachment(attachment.ArticleId);       
    EventAggregator.Publish(ViewTags.ATTACHMENT_DETAILS_VIEW.AsViewNavigationArgs());
    EventAggregator.Publish(new CurrentViewMessage(ContentView.Attachment));
}
```

I would like to pass the object state of AvailAttachment class from AttachmentsViewModel to MainMenuViewModel. presently null value comes for AvailAttachment's attachment object in MainMenuViewModel. I am debugging a code written by someone. This is a silverlight project using MVVM model. How do I do that?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to pass it via events? I usually use the [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921173.aspx)

Comment: I tried using eventaggregator. I could publish the articleid value in the attachmentviewmodel. But when I try to subscribe from mainmenuviewmodel, it is not accepting the object. I get this error. The best overloaded method match for 'Jounce.Core.Event.IEventAggregator.Subscribe<Debi.Data.Entities.PropertyModel.AvailAttachment>(Jounce.Core.Event.IEventSink<Debi.Data.Entities.PropertyModel.AvailAttachment>)' has some invalid arguments        C:\DeBi\trunk\src\Debi.Sl.Rock\ViewModels\Menu\MainMenuViewModel.cs